# Spring passing CGLIB proxy object to the @Repository layer and Hibernate

Tags: spring, spring-aop, cglib

This is more a conceptual question i.e.

I am using Spring Application Context to instantiate and manage my objects. i have an application that consists of the following layers.

Model(DAO), Repository, Service

Now in the Repository  and the Service layers all Classes implement there corresponding interfaces and i am able to call a method of those layer simply by calling the method of the corresponding  interface for example:

```
@Autowired
public IUserRepository iUserRepository;
iUserRepository.doSomething();
```

In my Model(DAO) layer i have classes that are annotated with

```
@Repository
@Entity
@Table(name = "USERS")
public class Users {
...
}
```

The problem that i am facing is the flowing. In my  Service layer when i try to instantiate an object from the Model (DAO) layer i.e. :

```
Users userTest =  (Users)context.getBean("users");
```

i get the  object of type "Users", however that is not exactly "Users" object but a  proxy object instantiated trough CGLIB based proxy.
That proxy object has additional Attributes. See attached picture from the debugging.
[image]

When i try to pass it further to my repository layer i get the error listed below

If i instantiate an object of the same class with the operator "new", then everything works well i.e i am able to save that object in the database.

```
user = new Users();

iUserRepository.createUser(user);
```

Till now i have learned that i shell NOT use the "new" operator in Spring i.e. Spring Application context(container) shell manage all of the objects however  how to deal with this scenario.

My DAO Users object does have a default constructor but does not implement any interfaces thus JdkDynamicAopProxy is not being used, instead  CGLIB based proxy is created. But that proxy object is not accepted as a User object of my repository later i.e. i get that "org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: " error message.

The question is what is the "right" construct/constellation i.e. is it ok to use the new operator or am i making some typical mistake that i am not aware of it yet.

```
2014-10-12 11:13:53.707 ERROR 8388 --- [           main] o.s.R.account.UserRepositoryImpl         : Exception

org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: org.syncServer.Model.acount.Users$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$54139ff4
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1095)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1439)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:711)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:703)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:698)
    at org.syncServer.Repository.account.UserRepositoryImpl.create(UserRepositoryImpl.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.syncServer.Service.account.UserServiceImpl.create(UserServiceImpl.java:266)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.create(Unknown Source)
    at org.syncServer.core.Tests.createUser(Tests.java:44)
    at org.syncServer.core.Application.main(Application.java:95)
```

Comment: And why wouldn't you create a new instance of the `User` yourself? There is nothing wrong with using `new User()`. Also why would your `User` be a `@Repository` anyway?. You want to wire your application (services, repositories) and infrastructure (queues, datasources) but in general not your business objects.

Comment: Hello Deinum, i have chosen "Repository" annotation for the Model(DAO) as this was the recommended one for Model(DAO) and Repository layers. I found this recommendation on Stackoverflow. I could marked it as Component but that Annotation does not reflect the purpose of that class. Since i am more or less new to Spring i did not new exactly what is the right way to do it, nevertheless the question still remains why Spring does not recognize that proxy object as a Users object instead gives me that hibernate exception 
"org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity:"

Comment: You have a repository which should be annotated with `@Repository`. Your model, generally, isn't spring managed (unless you use a rich domain or active record or the likes). The fact that you use spring or di doesn't mean every class needs to be managed...

Comment: Deinum, thank you for your response, i guess that was what i was searching for i.e. the confirmation that "generally" the model should not be manage by spring. Is there however the possibility to do manage the model with spring? Is yes what that will be?

Answer (score 2):

Seem like you are trying to create an [Active Record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern) by mixin directly JPA entities with spring-data `Repositories`.

Although it is not acceptable to many people, IMHO this approach will work better via composition, ie injecting Repositories in entites, not extending them via cglib proxies.

for example:

```
public interface ActiveRecord {
    void save();
    User load(Long id);
    void delete();
}

interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

}

@Configurable
class User implements ActiveRecord {
    @Id
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    @Transient @Autowired 
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public void save() {
        this.repository.save(this);

    }
    @Override
    public User load(Long id) {
        return repository.findOne(id);

    }
    @Override
    public void delete() {
        this.repository.delete(this);
    }
}
```

Note that you need to weaving with `AspectJ`, because entities are usually created by the ORM or application code and not by Spring container.

```
User user = new User();
user.setName("test");
user.save();
```

Comment: Jose thank you for your comment i will consider that approach in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I got the similar problem. This is becuase Hibernate by default uses `entity.getClass().getName()` to resolve the entity name, as shown in the last line of 
 the decomplied code below from class `CoordinatingEntityNameResolver`

```
 public String resolveEntityName(Object entity) {
        String entityName = this.interceptor.getEntityName(entity);
        if (entityName != null) {
            return entityName;
        } else {
            Iterator var3 = this.sessionFactory.getMetamodel().getEntityNameResolvers().iterator();

            while(var3.hasNext()) {
                EntityNameResolver resolver = (EntityNameResolver)var3.next();
                entityName = resolver.resolveEntityName(entity);
                if (entityName != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }

            return entityName != null ? entityName : entity.getClass().getName();
        }
    }
```

In the first line, you can see that it tried to resolve the name first using [hibernate's interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Interceptor.html).

You can customize the interceptor and override entity name resolving logic as shown below

```
public class EntityProxySupportHibernateInterceptor extends EmptyInterceptor {
    @Override
    public String getEntityName(Object object) {
        return AopUtils.getTargetClass(object).getName();
    }
}
```

In my case, I use Spring's `AopUitls.getTargetClass()` becuase I wrapped by entity with Spring's aop proxy. If you use other kind of proxy (such as the original cglib), you can change the implementation as appropriate.

Then register it in `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.ejb.interceptor=com.your.package.EntityProxySupportHibernateInterceptor
```